# Redux state with paginated relational data

Tags: wordpress, redux

How would you approach the Redux state shape and/or reducers composition for paginated **and** relationnal data, such as paginated posts from a specific category fetched from a Wordpress API (eg.: .../posts?categories=11) ?

I'm currently dealing it this way:

```
const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'RECEIVE_POSTS': {
      const { data } = action.payload.result // posts ids
      return { ...state, [action.meta.page || '1']: data }
    }
    default: return state
  }
}

const list = (listName, predicate, getSublistName) => (state, action) => {
  if (action.error || listName != predicate(action)) {
    return state
  } else if (getSublistName) {
    const sublistName = getSublistName(action)
    return { ...state, [sublistName]: reducer(state[sublistName], action) }
  }
  return reducer(state, action)
}

export default combineReducers({
  categories: list(
    'categories',
    (action) => action.meta && action.meta.list,
    (action) => action.meta && head(action.meta.categories)) // head comes from Lodash
  ),
  search: list(
    'search', 
    (action) => action.meta && action.meta.list
  ),
  ...
}
```

It works, but I feel that either the `list` higher order reducer could be improved by being agnostic in regard to a deeper nesting (which feels wrong...), or the resulting state shape is nested too much.

I can't wrap my head to get a totally flat state, except by using entries like a `postsCategories` array of posts objects with a post/category id and page number, but then data would be duplicated a lot (which feels also wrong...).

There are [some libraries for pagination](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/use-cases.md#pagination) but I don't believe any of them handle this.

Is it about reducer composition or state shape? Both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I post my own answer since I believe it's perfectly working for this specific case of paginated and relational state coming from a WP API.

I flattened my state shape by using query strings (used in requests to WP API) as keys for naming each posts lists in state. So it now looks like this :

```
entities: {
    posts: {
        byId: { ... },
        byList: {
            'page=1': [...], // post ids
            'categories=1&page=1': [...], // post ids
            'search=foo': [...] // post ids
        },
    },
}
```

Posts lists are easily shareable through all view components.
I can select a list by using `params` or `search` from React Router `match` or `location`, respectively, and get a URLs system working either with categories/foo/page/1 or categories=foo&page=1, like in WP core.

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach for managing relational data in a Redux store is "normalization".  See the [Structuring Reducers - Normalizing State Shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) section in the docs, and some of the articles in the [Redux Techniques - Selectors and Normalization](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-techniques.md#selectors-and-normalization) section of my React/Redux links list.

As far as pagination, the article [Advanced Redux Entity Normalization](https://medium.com/@dcousineau/advanced-redux-entity-normalization-f5f1fe2aefc5) has some useful examples of how to track multiple subsets of normalized data in the store.

It's also worth noting that there's already at least one library dedicated to providing a React/Redux interface to a Wordpress API, called [kasia](https://github.com/outlandishideas/kasia).

Comment: Thank you Mark. My example is already using normalized data but I should have make it more obvious that `action.payload.result.data` is an array of ids and that posts data are store elsewhere. I already looked at Kasia and also Calypso... I will take some time to better understand their code. I quickly scanned over the article Advanced Redux Entity Normalization, and it reminds me that I thought about using abitrary names for slices of state like `categoryFoo-page1`... Is it the recommanded best practice? I know I should also look at Redux ORM.